# Variable inside controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following json:

```
{
"id": "026001",
"description": "Drop Forged Double Coupler",
"CASHCUST01": {
    "hireRate": "0.01500",
    "saleRate": "2.50000"

},
"SMITH00010": {
    "hireRate": "0.02500",
    "saleRate": "1.50000"

},
"imageUrl": "images/fitting.jpg"
}
```

My controller:

```
var userLogged = 'SMITH00010';

$scope.updateValue = function(qtd) {
  $scope.newHireRate = $scope.product.{{userLogged}}.hireRate * qtd;
}
```

I want to show the right price of the product based on what user is logged in.

It's not working this way, I'm sure there is a way to do it, anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update from

```
$scope.newHireRate = $scope.product.{{userLogged}}.hireRate * qtd;
```

to

```
$scope.newHireRate = $scope.product[userLogged].hireRate * qtd;
```